# Error while building project with ExportSWC plugin in FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, plugins, flex4, flashdevelop

I am making a ActionScript library which is a Flex 4 project for my Adobe AIR Native Extension in FlashDevelop. When I build the project its successful, but when I try to build the project with ExportSWC plugin to get .swc file I get the following message:

```
Prebuilding config C:\Users\Osama Mohammed\Documents\AndroidSIPManager\obj\AndroidSIPManager.flex.compc.xml...
Configuration writen to: C:\Users\Osama Mohammed\Documents\AndroidSIPManager\obj\AndroidSIPManager.flex.compc.xml
Running Process:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk\bin\compc.exe" -load-config+="C:\Users\Osama Mohammed\Documents\AndroidSIPManager\obj\AndroidSIPManager.flex.compc.xml" 
Error loading: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
Building AsDoc
AsDoc temp output: C:\Users\Osama Mohammed\AppData\Local\Temp\7827039c-c329-4b6d-acb7-447146a5f4fe
Start AsDoc: C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexsdk\bin\asdoc.exe
-lenient=true -keep-xml=true -skip-xsl=true -output "C:\Users\Osama  Mohammed\AppData\Local\Temp\7827039c-c329-4b6d-acb7-447146a5f4fe"  -source-path "c:\users\osama mohammed\documents\androidsipmanager\src"  -doc-classes com.innovative.androidsipmanager.AndroidSIPManager com.innovative.androidsipmanager.Main  -exclude-dependencies=true -target-player=10.1
```

Following is the error:

```
Error loading: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
AsDoc complete (6)
Build failed (6).
```

Please help me in solving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove Java 64 bit & install Java 32 bit. Now it is working.